# Connection leaks causing TimeoutException when using C3P0

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm using Carbonado, which is Amazon's open source object relational mapper. Carbonado is like Hibernate. My service contains a public API method for accessing the database using Carbonado. This method works fine for the first few calls. However if I call this method repeatedly, then I
get the following error:

```
com.amazon.carbonado.FetchException: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool
```

Please help me fix the error.

Thank you

Comment: do you have a Connection leak, as your title suggests? in that case be sure that your public API method reliably close()es the Connections that it opens. otherwise, you should probably provide much more information. you can make the particular error you are seeing go away by setting the c3p0 config parameter checkoutTimeout to zero (which would have been itse default). without a checkoutTimeout, if what you have is a Connection leak, the application would simply hang. it could be that nothing is wrong, and you just have checkoutTimeout set to too low a value. configuration information, please.

Comment: After I restart the server, I could always call the method successfully 8 times. However after calling it 8 times, the method always return the same error.

Comment: maybe then a Connection leak, if maxPoolSize is 8. if so, you'll have to fix it -- make sure that Connections opened get close()ed.

Comment: @Steve Waldman Thanks for your help. The problem was caused by the Cursor not being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the Cursor not being closed.